# What does the column "created" in the list of tag synonyms mean?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

The [list of tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) contains a column called "created". Does this column contain the date when a synonym was proposed or the date when the synonym was approved?

For example, on Mathematics Stack Exchange the tag ([holomorphic-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holomorphic-functions)) is a [synonym of complex analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/complex-analysis/synonyms). When I check the [list of tag synonyms](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) (and looking at [the active synonyms](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Active)) the date shown there is from May 2016. However, I can see it as a separate tag in a snapshot from [February 2017](http://web.archive.org/web/20170218023423/https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holomorphic-functions) archived in Wayback Machine.

Additional question: If this table shows when the synonym was proposed, is there also a way to find out when the synonym was actually created/approved? Is there some other way than checking the data from SEDE?

Comment: do you mean the "active" or the "pending approval" view? Or both?

Comment: I have edited the post to clarify that I meant [active](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Active) synonyms rather than [pending approval](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Suggested). (I see that both of them have a column called created - for pending synonyms, the most logical meaning of the date seems the be the date when the synonym was proposed.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is what the label promises, the creationdate of the synonym and that is the date the synonym got proposed.

Here is how I reach that conclusion:

Lets look at the list, specially the synonym for total-reputation. I picked that one because it was created by a non-diamond.

[image]

Now look at this [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1178480):

[image]

The approval date is in June, but Cody created/proposed that synonym on Mar, 24th.

The date shown is the date the tagsynonym row was inserted in the table, or to say it in your words, the date the synonym was proposed.

Let remind ourselves that the Tag Synonym Dashboard got an overhaul in June 2019: [Tag synonym dashboard 2.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329687/tag-synonym-dashboard-2-0)