# I'm getting an error dialog when retracting close votes, but they did seem to succeed

Tags: bug, status-completed, retracted-close-votes

This is most likely a problem on the server side, but FYI I'm using the 64-bit version of FireFox 72.0.2 on Windows 7. As the title states, when I tried retracting a close vote, I got an error dialog:

[image: Error dialog when retracting a close vote, with it saying "An error occurred; please try again"]

However, the underlying question close count has been reduced by 1, including when I refresh the screen. This indicates the retraction was successful.

Just now, on Math SE, I was checking a few of my recent close votes, where the question was still open, to see if the OP had improved the question so it was appropriate for me to retract the close vote. I found 2 such cases, with the error above occurring both times. Just to help make sure, I found a third one and tried it again, with the same error occurring.

I don't retract close votes very often, with the last time being at least a few weeks ago, but I've done quite a few times now overall, and I've never encountered an error before.

**Update:**

This worked fine with Google Chrome 80.0.3987.106 on both the Windows 7 machine mentioned above, as well as a Windows 10 machine. However, on the Win 7 machine, I updated Firefox to 73.0, with it still causing the same error, Also, I get the same error with Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0 on Windows 10 (one small difference is although the close count with Firefox while the dialog was showing was updated, this didn't occur with Edge)! It seems to be an issue with certain browsers, in particular at least Firefox & Edge.

One final thing is, at least with Edge which I noticed twice & I believe I also saw it with Firefox, there's a flash of blue before the red error dialog appears, indicating the browser first thinks the operation succeeded before it displayed the error dialog.

Comment: I can't repro here on MSE, I'm on Chrome, Win 10.

Comment: @rene Thanks for checking. I've found using Chrome, both on Win 7 & Win 10, that it works fine. However, this same problem keeps happening with Firefox on a Win 7 machine. I've updated my question accordingly to give this extra info.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Thanks for the ping, I'm responding here to keep the conversation close to the report. :) That's... strange. I'd expect something like that to be a server-side issue, but I guess here we are. We'll investigate further on our end, but also out of curiosity - are you running any extensions on the affected browsers?

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks for the reply. I've deleted my other comment. Re: your question, I'm not running any extensions on the affected browsers. I haven't even made very many settings changes on them. They are basically just the standard versions you get when you they're initially installed. Note since it seems, as I stated in my update, the dialog for success first appears, my guess is that somehow the browser code is later determining somewhat went wrong inappropriately. If you have any trouble reproducing this on either Firefox or Edge, please let me know, including anything I can help with.

Comment: @AdamLear As my answer indicates, I now can't recreate the error. I'm not sure if something changed on your end (e.g., the HTML script code being used), but as I wrote below, I consider this issue to be resolved for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem is no longer occurring when I now just recently checked. With Firefox on Windows 7, the error dialog didn't occur during any of the 3 times that I retracted a close vote a few hours ago. Note that on the Win 7 machine, I have previously updated Firefox to 73.0.1. However, on Windows 10, the version of Edge hasn't changed (with it still being 44.18362.449.0), but the error dialog also didn't occur during the one time I retracted a close vote.

Thus, it seems the error not happening now is not due to the browser version changing. Regardless of the reason(s) for it, I now can't produce that error so I consider the issue to be resolved at this time.

**Update:** As stated in [Adam Lear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/155160/adam-lear)'s [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343717/im-getting-an-error-dialog-when-retracting-close-votes-but-they-did-seem-to-su/344360#comment1153873_344360) below,

> I fixed a bug earlier this week where the "retract vote" button would sometimes also attempt to submit a new vote as well (which clearly failed), but completely didn't connect that in my head with this report. So yeah, it should be fixed!

Comment: Oh hey, I think I know what this was. I fixed a bug earlier this week where the "retract vote" button would sometimes also attempt to submit a new vote as well (which clearly failed), but completely didn't connect that in my head with this report. So yeah, it should be fixed!

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks for letting me know. What you describe definitely matches the behavior I saw. What I'm surprised about is why that error dialog didn't occur in Chrome (I guess that's where the "sometimes" part comes in). If you don't mind, please put this into an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.