# Partially hidden tooltip on tag synonym page

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, tag-synonyms, tooltips

When you're a moderator, the column with the [awkwardly designed voting buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329688/295232)  on the [tag synonyms page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) is hidden, because ♦ moderators don't need to vote on them; they can simply approve them. However, that causes the popover for the Score column to be partially hidden:

[image]

Comment: I think this is can also be reproducible even on non-mod mode (depending on the page width). But to be sure we just need to find the site where there are pending approval tags (i.e. user has score 5+ for these tags).